# Missing children nodes within DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I am using DOM to retrieve children of my element node whose class name is 'main' as indicated in the html snippet below.
It seems to me that there 9 children elements under the parent element. but i was surprised
by the children nodes values. Does anyone has an explanation for the output below

```
<section class="main">
 <h2>Page Title</h2>
 <h3>Article Heading</h3>
 <p>First Paragraph</p>
 <p>Second Paragraph</p>
 <p>Third Paragraph</p>
 <p>Fourth Paragraph</p>
 <h3>Instructions</h3>
 <p>Fifth Paragraph</p>
 <p>Sixth Paragraph</p>
</section>
```

JS code:

```
var articleHeadElemNode = document.querySelector(".main");
console.log(articleHeadElemNode.childElementCount);

for (i =0; i<articleHeadElemNode.childElementCount ; i++ )
  console.log(articleHeadElemNode.childNodes[i]);
```

Final Output:

```
9
#text
<h2>​Page Title​</h2>​
#text
<h3>​Article Heading​</h3>​
#text
<p>​First Paragraph​</p>​
#text
<p>​Second Paragraph​</p>​
#text
```

Where are the rest of paragraphs? I managed to retrieve the elements using 
document.querySelector(".main > h3") or using querySelectorAll but I am interested in logical explanation for what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are reading `childElementCount` which is count of childNodes that have `nodeType` of `1` and you are reading all the `childNodes` in the loop which also returns the `textNode`s that have `nodeType` of `3`. You should use the `children` property in the loop instead of the `childNodes`.

Comment: I was expecting that I have 9 child node elements starting form <h2>Page Title</h2> till <p>Sixth Paragraph</p>, where do these text nodes come from?

Comment: @WaelShowair Those are in your markup, the whitespaces and other invisible characters. You can remove them and check the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You're best off using [`Element.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.children) for child elements. [`Element.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.children) returns only element node children, while [`Node.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.childNodes) will return all node children:

```
for(var i = 0; i < articleHeadElemNode.childElementCount; i++)
  console.log(articleHeadElemNode.children[i]);
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2phaw4y/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that I can use children instead. I am asking about explanation of the output: I was expecting that I have 9 child node elements starting form <h2>Page Title</h2> till <p>Sixth Paragraph</p>, where do these text nodes come from? and why the rest html tags are not included as child nodes?